# How do I fill merged cells or unmerge cells in a XLSX worksheet in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sheetjs

I am using the XLSX package with typescript. Given some data like

```
data 1 | data 2 | data 3 |
       | abc1   | xyz 2  |
       | abc2   | xyz 3  |
```

I want to attain

```
data 1 | data 2 | data 3 |
data 1 | abc1   | xyz 2  |
data 1 | abc2   | xyz 3  |
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a simple function for doing this on the internet, so I wrote one myself. Hope this comes in useful.

```
function fillMerges(ws: XLSX.WorkSheet){
    if(ws["!merges"]){
        for(let merge of ws["!merges"]){
            for (let i1=merge.s.c; i1<=merge.e.c; i1++){
                for(let i2=merge.s.r; i2<=merge.e.r; i2++){
                    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(
                        ws,
                        [[ws[XLSX.utils.encode_col(merge.s.c)+XLSX.utils.encode_row(merge.s.r)].v]],
                        {origin: XLSX.utils.encode_col(i1)+XLSX.utils.encode_row(i2)}
                    )
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
function parseExcel(file: File) {

    return new Promise<{name: string, sheet: any[]}[]>((resolve, reject)=>{
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var sheets: {name: string, sheet: any[]}[] = []

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            if (e.target) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type: 'binary'
                });
                workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName: string) {
                    // Here is your object
                    fillMerges(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                    var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                    sheets.push({name: sheetName, sheet:XL_row_object});
                })
                resolve(sheets);
            }
        };

        reader.onerror = function (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    });

};
```